# Azure Redis Cache connected list

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to understand what is "client list" command from redis showing me. I was of the opinion that it shows me number of clients connected to redis irrespective of commands issued from the connected clients.
For e.g: If I have a webapp connected to local redis server I am hoping to see one entry for the web app when I issue "client list"

But what I saw was below:
Initial connect and firing redis SetAsync (I see 2 entries different ports in addr):

id=4 **addr=[::1]:56674** laddr=[::1]:6379 fd=9 name= age=16 idle=4 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 ssub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 multi-mem=0 rbs=1280 rbp=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=2184 events=r cmd=set user=default redir=-1 resp=2 lib-name=SE.Redis lib-ver=2.6.122.38350

id=5 **addr=[::1]:56676** laddr=[::1]:6379 fd=10 name= age=16 idle=16 flags=P db=0 sub=1 psub=0 ssub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 multi-mem=0 rbs=1024 rbp=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=1984 events=r cmd=subscribe user=default redir=-1 resp=2 lib-name=SE.Redis lib-ver=2.6.122.38350

When issuing GetAsync (I see 2 entries different ports in addr):

id=4 **addr=[::1]:56674** laddr=[::1]:6379 fd=9 name= age=359 idle=4 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 ssub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 multi-mem=0 rbs=1280 rbp=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=2184 events=r cmd=get user=default redir=-1 resp=2 lib-name=SE.Redis lib-ver=2.6.122.38350

id=5 **addr=[::1]:56676** laddr=[::1]:6379 fd=10 name= age=359 idle=6 flags=P db=0 sub=1 psub=0 ssub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 multi-mem=0 rbs=1024 rbp=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=1984 events=r cmd=ping user=default redir=-1 resp=2 lib-name=SE.Redis lib-ver=2.6.122.38350

Why are there extra entries? Does each set or get or keyexists request open a new connection?

Answer (score 0):

- In the case of the StackExchange.Redis library, each `IDatabase` instance represents a pool of connections to a Redis server. Within this pool, connections can be reused for multiple operations, and the library manages the connections for you. So, multiple `SET`, `GET`, or `KeyExists` requests will typically reuse connections from the connection pool rather than opening a completely new connection for each request.
  [image]
- StackExchange.Redis uses a connection pool to manage connections to the Redis server, and multiple commands like `SET`, `GET`, or `KeyExists` can reuse connections from this pool rather than opening a new connection for each request.
- the `CLIENT LIST` command provides information about client connections to the Redis server. Each line in the output represents a single client connection.
- The multiple entries for different connections, and each entry provides information about that specific connection.

**Sample code using `set` and `get`:**

```cs
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Connection string for your Azure Redis Cache instance
        string connectionString = "geetharedis.redis.cache.wi";
        ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
        IDatabase database = connection.GetDatabase();
        database.StringSet("myKey", "Hello, Redis!");
         string value = database.StringGet("myKey");
         Console.WriteLine($"Value retrieved from Redis: {value}");
         connection.Close();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]